# SQL Server Insert Using View

Tags: sql-server

This is a simplified example of what I want to do.  Assume there is table named contractor that looks like this:

```
name | paid_adjustment_amount | adj_date
Bob  | 1000                   | 4/7/2016
Mary | 2000                   | 4/8/2016
Bill | 5000                   | 4/8/2016
Mary | 4000                   | 4/10/2016
Bill | (1000)                 | 4/12/2016
Ann  | 3000                   | 4/30/2016
```

There is a view of the contractor table, let's call it v_sum, that is just a SUM of the paid_adustment_amount grouped by name.  So it looks like this:

```
name | total_paid_amount
Bob  | 1000
Mary | 6000
Bill | 4000
Ann  | 3000
```

Finally, there is another table called to_date_payment that looks like this:

```
name | paid_to_date_amount
Bob  | 1000
Mary | 8000
Bill | 3000
Ann  | 3000
Joe  | 4000
```

I want to compare the information in the to_date_payment table to the v_sum view and insert a new row in the contractor table to show an adjustment.  Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO contractor
SELECT to_date_payment.name, 
    to_date_payment.paid_to_date_amount - v_sum.total_paid_amount,
    GETDATE()
FROM to_date_payment
LEFT JOIN v_sum ON to_date_payment.name = v_sum.name
WHERE to_date_payment.paid_to_date_amount - v_sum.total_paid_amount <> 0
    OR v_sum.name IS NULL
```

Are there any issues with using a view for this?  My understanding, please correct me if I'm wrong, is that a view is just a result set of a query.  And, since the view is of the table I'm inserting new records into, I'm afraid there could be data integrity problems.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fully understand what you are doing, you should also provide the definition for `v_sum`. Generally speaking, views might provide some advantages, especially when indexed. More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378068/when-to-use-a-view-instead-of-a-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439056/is-a-view-faster-than-a-simple-query).

Simple usage of views do not provide performance benefits, but they are very good of providing abstraction over tables.

In your particular case, I do not see any problem in JOINing with the view, but I would worry about potential problems related to:

**1) JOIN using VARCHARs instead of integer** - ON to_date_payment.name = v_sum.name - if possible, try to `JOIN` on integer (ids or foreign keys ids) values, as it is faster (indexes applied on integer columns will have a smaller key, comparisons are slightly faster).

**2) OR in queries** - usually leads to performance problems. One thing to try is to change the SELECT like this:

```
SELECT to_date_payment.name, 
    to_date_payment.paid_to_date_amount - v_sum.total_paid_amount,
    GETDATE()
FROM to_date_payment
JOIN v_sum ON to_date_payment.name = v_sum.name
WHERE to_date_payment.paid_to_date_amount - v_sum.total_paid_amount <> 0

UNION ALL

SELECT to_date_payment.name, 
    to_date_payment.paid_to_date_amount,    -- or NULL if this is really intended
    GETDATE()
FROM to_date_payment
-- NOT EXISTS is usually faster than LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM v_sum V WHERE V.name = to_date_payment.name)
```

**3) Possible undesired result** - by default, arithmetic involving NULL returns NULL. When there is no match in v_sum, then `v_sum.total_paid_amount` is NULL and to_date_payment.paid_to_date_amount - v_sum.total_paid_amount will evaluate to NULL. Is this correct? Maybe `to_date_payment.paid_to_date_amount - ISNULL(v_sum.total_paid_amount, 0)` is intended.

Comment: Thanks! #1 Unfortunately I don't have control over the unique identifiers. They are not names, but they are alphanumeric combinations (e.g. AB123) provided from an outside source that require VARCHAR. #2 I have used UNIONs in place of OR before. But, should I avoid all ORs and INs? I can think of an unrelated query where I have a criteria that has 6 items in the IN clause. Should I instead write 6 queries with 5 unions??? #3 Good catch.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: #2. This should be considered based on actual execution plan. If you do not have a very large number of records, OR/IN might still get a reasonable time. Also, for complex queries you can define a temporary table and perform several inserts. Besides possible performance optimizations, it also allows easier debugging (check temporary after each insert).