# Rails 5 complex query with multiple sub queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm on rails 5 using postgres and I have a users table and a reports table. Users have many reports, and these reports need to be created every day. I want to fetch all of the users that are not archived, that have not completed a report today, and show yesterdays report notes if available.

Here are the models:

**Users Model**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  name       :string           not null
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  archived   :boolean          default(FALSE)
#

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reports
end
```

**Reports Model**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: reports
#
#  id         :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  notes      :text
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  user_id    :bigint(8)
#

class Report < ApplicationRecord
  belongd_to :user
end
```

Here is an example of what I want from this query:

**Users Table**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |  name  | archived |         created_at         |         updated_at         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  Jonn  |  false   | 2018-05-11 00:01:36.124999 | 2018-05-11 00:01:36.124999 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |  Sam   |  false   | 2018-05-11 00:01:36.124999 | 2018-05-11 00:01:36.124999 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | Ashley |  true    | 2018-05-11 00:01:36.124999 | 2018-05-11 00:01:36.124999 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Reports Table (Imagine this report was yesterdays)**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |  user_id  |  notes  |         created_at         |         updated_at         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |     1     | Nothing | 2018-06-13 16:32:05.139284 | 2018-06-13 16:32:05.139284 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Desire output:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id |  name  | archived |         created_at         |         updated_at         | yesterdays_notes |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |  Jonn  |  false   | 2018-05-11 00:01:36.124999 | 2018-05-11 00:01:36.124999 |     Nothing      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |  Sam   |  false   | 2018-05-11 00:01:36.124999 | 2018-05-11 00:01:36.124999 |       NULL       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I was able to get the desired query results writing raw SQL, but I have run into a lot of issues trying to convert it to an active record query. Would this be an appropriate scenario to use the [scenic gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/scenic)?

Here is the raw SQL query:

```
SELECT u.*, (
  SELECT notes AS yesterdays_notes
  FROM reports AS r
  WHERE r.created_at >= '2018-06-13 04:00:00'
  AND r.created_at <= '2018-06-14 03:59:59.999999'
  AND r.user_id = u.id
)
FROM users AS u
WHERE u.archived = FALSE
AND u.id NOT IN (
  SELECT rr.user_id
  FROM reports rr
  WHERE rr.created_at >= '2018-06-14 04:00:00'
);
```

Comment: I am not experienced in `scenic` to advise or discourge, though what were the issues while converting to AR. Also this can be converted to a join query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the desired results from the 2 answers posted here, however, after doing some more research I think using a database view using the [scenic gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/scenic) is the appropriate approach here so I am going to move forward with that.

Thank you for the input! If you want to see some of the reasoning behind my decision this stackoverflow post summarizes it nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4378166/2909095

Here is what I ended up with using the [scenic gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/scenic). I changed the actual query a little bit to fit my needs better but it resolves this answer:

Model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: missing_reports
#
#  id                  :bigint(8)
#  name                :string
#  created_at          :datetime
#  updated_at          :datetime
#  previous_notes      :text
#  previous_notes_date :datetime

class MissingReport < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Database View

```
SELECT u.*, rs.notes AS previous_notes, rs.created_at AS previous_notes_date
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT r.*
  FROM reports AS r
  WHERE r.created_at < TIMESTAMP 'today'
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
  LIMIT 1
) rs ON rs.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.archived = FALSE
AND u.id NOT IN (
  SELECT rr.user_id
  FROM standups rr
  WHERE rr.created_at >= TIMESTAMP 'today'
);
```

Usage

```
def index
  @missing_reports = MissingReport.all
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

First, select all active users with most recent reports created yesterday and assign it to a var:

```
users = User.where(archived: false).joins(:reports)
.where.not('DATE(reports.created_at) IN (?)', [Date.today]) 
.where('DATE(reports.created_at) IN (?)', [Date.yesterday])
.select('users.id', 'users.name', 'notes')
```

now the users var will have the attrs listed in `.select` available so you can call `users.map(&:notes)` to see the list of nodes, including `nil` / `null` notes.

another trick that may come in handy is the ability to alias the attrs your listed in `.select`. For example, if you want to store `users.id` as `id`, you can do so with

```
...
.select('users.id as id', 'users.name', 'reports.notes')
```

you can call `users.map(&:attributes)` to see what these final structs would look like

more info on available Active Record querying can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try this out last night, but I'll give it a shot maybe on my lunch break. Just looking at your code examples, I don't think this would work because I need to also only get users who have not made a report today. I'll let you know.

Comment: @Nitsew. added an additional `where` clause to filter out reports that were made today

Comment: I think that could work actually, I think the only thing I would need to change is to make the standups a left outer join. I'll follow up with you about it a little later. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
users = User.joins(:reports).where("(reports.created_at < ? OR reports.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (users.archived = ?)", Date.today.beginning_of_day, Date.yesterday.beginning_of_day, Date.yesterday.end_of_day, false).select("users.id, users.name, reports.notes").uniq
```

users will return as `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [....]`

Possibly joins returns duplicate records so use `uniq`

Filter reports

```
reports.created_at < Date.today.beginning_of_day OR yesterday.beginning_of_day > reports.created_at < Yesterday.end_of_day
```

which is required reports as "not completed a report today, and show yesterdays report notes if available"

And `users.archived = false`

Comment: I believe its `distinct` in Rails 5. Great answer otherwise

Comment: I don't think this is going to give me the desired results because I only need users who have not made a report today. I'll play with it sometime today when I have some free time to toy around with it.

Comment: @Nitsew Please have a look to updated answer, and let me know for further guidance. thanks

Comment: Hey @Gabbar, I posted an answer on here you can check out. I think the best approach is to use a database view in this instance due to the complexity. It is also going to get a little more difficult because the users won't be posting reports on saturday or sunday, so instead of always getting yesterdays report, I will have to add an edge case if the current date is Monday, get last Fridays report. Thank you for the help, it really helped me narrow down what solution to go with to be able to see other approaches and get feedback.