# Modify View at Runtime

Tags: mysql, database, view, phpmyadmin

Is that a Good practice to change the Structure of the View at Run Time?

I have created a VIEW

```
CREATE VIEW freligiouschk AS SELECT user_id, religion, caste FROM freligious WHERE religion IN ('Christian-Protestant','Christian-Orthodox','Hindu','Parsi','Christian-Others') OR caste IN ('Rajput','Kurmi/Kurmi Kshatriya','Veluthedathu Nair','Kuruhina Shetty','SKP')
```

The view is created
When a user clicks a button those values in the conditions with change Like this

```
CREATE VIEW freligiouschk AS SELECT user_id, religion, caste FROM freligious WHERE religion IN ('Jain-Digambar','Muslim-Others','Inter-Religion','Buddhist','NoReligiousBelief') OR caste IN ('Mahishya','SKP','Relli','Bhovi','Karmakar')
```

Is this a good Practice to change in Run time? What will happen if 2 or more users try to change the View at Same time?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a terrible idea. Views are shared across all database users (who have permissions to that object); changing the definition of the view while users are accessing it will lead to unexpected behaviour when more than one user accesses the system - in ways that are hard to test for.

It's also not necessary - views serve a bunch of [different purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278521/why-do-you-create-a-view-in-a-database), but it doesn't seem that what you are doing is one of them.