# How can I create a view with the last entry in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have a table with several entries of my users and I need to group by their ID's and retrieve the last register in the table.

To optimize my job, I have created a view using the query with a SELECT inside another for order by timestamp descendant, but it fails. I think it cannot build by views or already have a solution?

Please, if anyone know how can I do this, share!

Thanks!

P.S.: Sorry, here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    dg_users.id,
    dg_users.email,
    dg_maps.id,
    dg_maps.latitude,
    dg_maps.longitude,
    dg_maps.timestamp
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        dg_maps
    ORDER BY dg_maps.timestamp DESC) dg_maps
JOIN
    dg_geologs ON dg_geologs.map_id = dg_maps.id
JOIN
    dg_users ON dg_users.id = dg_geologs.user_id
GROUP BY dg_geologs.user_id;
```

Comment: Sorry, I was edited above.

Answer (score 2):

Based on that you have not published your table structure, I can only provide a general answer.
I would say though that I think making a view for such a small query doesn't provide that much of an advantage, unless you have a reason listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630200/when-to-use-database-views-and-when-not) ( [When to use database views and when not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630200/when-to-use-database-views-and-when-not) ).

In order to create a view with the last inserted entry you would do something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Where:

- **MyView** is the name you give to your view
- **myTable** is your table
- **timestamp** is the field with your timestamp

And you would query this with:

```
select * from MyView;
```

Comment: I have edited my post above. What I have to know in this query is the last entry for each registered user.

Comment: You should make a new question if it is different then the original.