# What is the purpose of Database View and when to use it

Tags: database, view

i want to know when to use view in a database...i know a little bit about view that it is a virtual table which is used to hold data from other tables temporally but i do not know when to use them in your app when you can collect data from different tables through sql joins and present it in HTML table...then what is the exact purpose of view??

Comment: There are heaps of articles you can read - this should get you started [Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214132/what-are-views-good-for)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use database views and when not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630200/when-to-use-database-views-and-when-not)